# Major sources of supplications

Tags: shia-sunni, dua

I want to know what are the major books for supplications? For Shia Muslims, I know the collection book of [mafatih-al-jinan](http://www.qul.org.au/library/duas-supplications) with all the supplications from the prophet and the 12 holy household. There, you can see supplication like [Kumayl](http://www.qul.org.au/library/duas-supplications/399-dua-kumayl-the-supplication-of-kumayl), [Munajat Imam Ali](http://www.qul.org.au/library/duas-supplications/414-munajat-e-imam-ali-whisper-prayer-of-imam-ali-as), [Munajat Shabaniya](http://www.qul.org.au/library/duas-supplications/413-munajat-e-shabaniya-the-invocation-of-the-month-of-shaban) and much more...

The question is if the sunni scholors consider these supplications to be authentic and if yes, do the Sunni Muslims recite them in daily life? What are the sources of supplications for Sunni Muslims? I need some examples!

Comment: One of the famous collections of supplications used by many sunni muslims is [Hisn Al Muslim Min Athkar Al Kitaab Was Sunnah](http://abdurrahman.org/zikr/Hisn_al_Muslim/frame.html) by Sa'eed Al Qahtani. It has Supplications from Qur'an and Sahih Hadiths.

Comment: You missed out [Sahifa-e-Sajjadiya](http://www.duas.org/sajjadiya/sajjadiya.htm) bro! :) And there are much more dua's [here](http://duas.org/).

Comment: @HashimR, yes I know but I just listed them as an example, the **much more...*** is because of that.

Comment: @Abdullah, why not putting it as an answer then?

Comment: @rowman Because part of your question, I do not know the answer. I do not know what shi'ite supplications are and what is the ruling regarding them.

Comment: @Abdullah, but the question is asking for the sources of supplications for Sunny Muslims as well.

Comment: @rowman I will make it an answer then, Insha Allah

Comment: It is sad that I have no sunny opinion regarding this issue.